# Does Aggressive Striking Iron Body stack with Berserker Adrenaline Rush?

Tags: combat, chronicles-of-darkness-1e, armor, fighting-style

Berserker is from Armory Reloaded, World of Darkness 1e.

I feel it would be a shame if it did not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they do not. From pg. 62 of Armory Reloaded:

> ### Combined Maneuvers
>
> Unless the text specifically notes otherwise, Fighting Style maneuvers
>   don't stack. If multiple maneuvers provide the same benefit within the
>   game system (a Defense bonus or dice bonus, for instance), your
>   character only benefits from the best of the lot.

Aggressive Striking 2 - Iron Body grants one point of armor against bashing attacks. Berserker 2 - Adrenaline Rush grants one point of armor against bashing and lethal attacks. Having both would mean your character would get one point of armor against bashing and lethal attacks.